# PythonCrashCourse Pg.151. TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Tags: python

In my book , Python Crash Course : This code is given but it gives an error.

```
def make_pizza(*toppings):
    """Summarize the pizza we are about to make."""
    print("\nMaking a pizza with the following toppings:")
    for topping in toppings:
        print("- " + topping)

make_pizza(make_pizza("peperoni"))

make_pizza(make_pizza("mushroom",'green peppers','extra cheese'))
```

The traceback is as follows:

print("- " + topping)

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

**Q. What is the NoneType object here ? Is it topping? If yes, why?**

Even when i use `str()` around `topping` , It gives me a funny output:

```
def make_pizza(*toppings):
"""Summarize the pizza we are about to make."""
print("\nMaking a pizza with the following toppings:")
for topping in toppings:
    print("- " + str(topping))

make_pizza(make_pizza("peperoni"))
make_pizza(make_pizza("mushroom",'green peppers','extra cheese'))
```

**Output:**

```
Making a pizza with the following toppings:

- peperoni

Making a pizza with the following toppings: 

- None

Making a pizza with the following toppings:
- mushroom
- green peppers
- extra cheese

Making a pizza with the following toppings:
- None
```

**Q2. Why is displaying 2 outputs for each?
- one with the list of toppings 
-and one with None ?**

Comment: You are overcooking the pizza. Don't make the same pizza 2 times. This `make_pizza(make_pizza("peperoni"))` should be `make_pizza("peperoni")` :D

Comment: Oh gosh! :D Sorry for that ! Thanks!

Comment: Accept theonlygusti's answer as he has clearly described what's happening in your script.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be passing the function to itself.

Replace these:

```
make_pizza(make_pizza("peperoni"))
make_pizza(make_pizza("mushroom",'green peppers','extra cheese'))
```

with

```
make_pizza("peperoni")
make_pizza("mushroom",'green peppers','extra cheese')
```

---

The reason that the error is happening is because you are passing the function `make_pizza`, which has no [return](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) value (it returns nothing), to itself.

*However*, the inner function still executes completely. That is, the second `make_pizza` in each of your examples is running properly, which is why you're getting two outputs.

For the second function though, you're effectively trying to run:

```
make_pizza(None)
```

Which of course leads to an error here:

```
print("- " + topping)
```

because `topping` is `None`.

---

The reason you sometimes saw `- None` in your output is because `str(None)` casts `None` to `"None"` (as in, a string containing the literal text `None`).